# how to construct an unordered pair data structure in matlab ?

Tags: matlab

How could I construct an unordered pair structure in matlab ?

Let us denote by E such a structure, where E = {(i,j), (k,p), ...} and  (i,j)=(j,i). So how to construct E in matlab ? Any suggestions ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could just use sorted arrays of length 2. By always keeping them sorted, you can easily compare them, and you will store both [2,1] and [1,2] in the same way.

Comment: @BasSwinckels but the problem is if I want to query if [2,1] is in the unordered set or not, what should I do ?

Comment: To see if some unknown pair is in the list, you first sort it, and then compare with all the items in the list ...

Answer (score 1):

What Bas Swinckels suggested is one way to store sets efficient. As each of your touples contains two elements, I would use a matrix with three constrains:

1. In each row, the first element is smaller than the second. Sort if nessecary. This way the touple (i,j) and (j,i) get the same representation.
2. Having 1. ensured, the rows must be unique to ensure each element is only present once.
3. To have a unique representation for the sets, sort the rows.

For any input, you could ensure the three properties using this code:

```
>> M=[1,2;2,1;3,2;1,3;3,1]

M =

     1     2
     2     1
     3     2
     1     3
     3     1

>> sortrows(unique(sort(M,2),'rows'))

ans =

     1     2
     1     3
     2     3
```

(`sortrows` is redundant for most matlab versions because `unique` alreads sorts)

Alternatives to the matrix representation is a cell:

```
{[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]}
```

it might be less performant, but you may extend this to tuples of different size. A last alternative, representing sets using bitmasks, does not seem to be efficient in this case.

Comment: thank you, but the problem is if I want to query if [2,1] is in the unordered set or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Any symmetrical matrices which have equal rows and column can satisfy your required condition:

`a = zeros(3)` or `b = ones(2)`

These two matrices are examples which are the same if you change their rows and columns, means:

`a( i, j ) = a( j, i );`

I hope this can help you.