# In matlab, if I construct an unordered array, how could I check if a member is in this array or not ?

Tags: matlab

Say, I can construct an unordered data structure in matlab using method:

[how to construct an unordered pair data structure in matlab ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462681/how-to-construct-an-unordered-pair-data-structure-in-matlab)

Now my question is if I want to query whether $(i,j)$ is in the unordered arrary $E$ , i.e., if (i,j) or (j,i) is in the row of E or not,  how could I implement that in matlab ?

Thank you very much

Comment: You can use `ismember` with the `'row'` property set. However, if you do this a lot it might be inefficient. Is there a reason why those points are unordered?

Comment: @jucestain thanks, for me, it reprent an edge of a undirected graph, thank you.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure which data structure you're using to store the points, but if it's an array, you can also use a self balancing binary search tree (AVL or red-black). You can store with log(n) and retrieve with log(n) as well. However, I'm not sure if Matlab supports these data structures yet... May be worth looking into if you algorithm becomes slow, but if speed isn't an issue then go ahead and keep it as-is.

Comment: The edges of an undirected graph should be a symmetric matrix. Then `E(i, j) == E(j, i)`. No searching is necessary.